# Why is the shell output txt file empty?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Kindly assist. I am working on a script that will perform a telnet test to a specific ip address on a specific TCP port and below is my script.

```
#! /bin/sh

nc -z -v -w5 192.168.88.55 3389 | tee results.txt
```

During execution, a "results.txt" file is created but it is empty. I want it to have the output of the script after execution.

Comment: What happens if you run it without the tee? Maybe nc is unable to connect (timeout) and there really is no stdout?

Comment: @BarryCarter there is the output ```connection to 192.168.88.55 port [tcp/ms-wbt-server] succeeded!```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve it by making the below modifications to the script

```
#! /bin/sh

nc -z -v -w5 192.168.88.55 3389 2>&1 | tee results.txt

sleep 5

exit
```

It is now able to write the output to the results.txt file.

Thank you.